# can someone turn columns from a different dataset as values in another dataset by matching values from a column in the first dataset with the second

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

sorry if I ain't clear, but got a challenge,

[this is the sample data I have generated to try to make my challenge clear] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wexWS.png)

sample data 1

| B | V | S | F | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.32 | 10.32 | 11.32 | 12.32 | 13.32 |
| 1.32 | 11.32 | 12.32 | 13.32 | 14.32 |
| 2.32 | 12.32 | 13.32 | 14.32 | 15.32 |
| 3.32 | 13.32 | 14.32 | 15.32 | 16.32 |
| 4.32 | 14.32 | 15.32 | 16.32 | 17.32 |
| 5.32 | 15.32 | 16.32 | 17.32 | 18.32 |
| 6.32 | 16.32 | 17.32 | 18.32 | 19.32 |
| 7.32 | 17.32 | 18.32 | 19.32 | 20.32 |
| 8.32 | 18.32 | 19.32 | 20.32 | 21.32 |
| 9.32 | 19.32 | 20.32 | 21.32 | 22.32 |
| 10.32 | 20.32 | 21.32 | 22.32 | 23.32 |

my expected output

| K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.32 |  |
| 2 | 3.32 |  |
| 3 | 4.32 |  |
| 4 | 5.32 |  |
| 5 | 6.32 |  |
| 6 | 13.32 |  |
| 7 | 14.32 |  |
| 8 | 15.32 |  |
| 9 | 16.32 |  |
| 10 | 17.32 |  |

[the second image explains the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pApV.png)

I would like to know how I would create another column M in dataset 2 that will  return the name of the column from dataset 1 contains the values in column L (which is in dataset 2)
I have tried the code below but it wasn't adding up to it since I had got this error and I thought someone here will help with this, thanks in advance!

````
spike_cols = [col for col in stata.columns if df['IMAGE NUMBER']  in col]```

returned the following error

```~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25368/552331776.py in <module>
----> 1 spike_cols = [col for col in stata.columns if df['IMAGE NUMBER']  in col]

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25368/552331776.py in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 spike_cols = [col for col in stata.columns if df['IMAGE NUMBER']  in col]

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series```
````

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from your data?[Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you get what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two dataframes here.For loop searches for matches and records column names for each row. You can also take dataframes from my message: df, df1 and place them in your message.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[0.32,1.32,2.32,3.32,4.32,5.32,6.32,7.32,8.32,9.32,10.32],
                   'V':[10.32,11.32,12.32,13.32,14.32,15.32,16.32,17.32,18.32,19.32,20.32],
                   'S':[11.32,12.32,13.32,14.32,15.32,16.32,17.32,18.32,19.32,20.32,21.32],
                   'F':[12.32,13.32,14.32,15.32,16.32,17.32,18.32,19.32,20.32,21.32,22.32],
                   'K':[13.32,14.32,15.32,16.32,17.32,18.32,19.32,20.32,21.32,22.32,23.32]})

print(df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'K':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                    'L':[2.32,3.32,4.32,5.32,6.32,13.32,14.32,15.32,16.32,17.32]})

M = []
for k in range(0, len(df1)):
    i, c = np.where(df == df1['L'][k])#Get the indexes of the columns where there was a match
    ttt = df.columns[c]#Get the name of the columns
    M.append(','.join(list(ttt)))#Output values to a comma-separated string if there are more than one values

df1['M'] = M #Adding a column with the received values

print(df1)
```